# How to convert a list of string to map in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, lambda, collections, functional-programming

How do I convert a List of

`("20-12-00", "98.78", "20-11,11","100.89")` to a map of `("20-12-00"->"98.78" ,  "20-11,11"->"100.89")` and access the value in the head of the map?

I already tried using the `.toMap` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List#grouped` to create a non-overlapping window:

```
list.grouped(2).map(l => (l(0), l(1))).toMap
```

Comment: yes i tried that but after when i try to get the value at head, it doesn't allow  me

Comment: @hateScala `res0.head`

Comment: ```.head``` returns the key value pair and i tried using ```.head.value``` but it doesn't work

Comment: @hateScala it's a tuple, use `.head._2`

Comment: ```val new_data = data.grouped(2).map(1 => (1(0), 1(1))).toMap
    Try(Some(new_data.head._2.toDouble)).getOrElse(None)``` returns a **indexOutOfBoundsException**

Comment: @hateScala mate, that's not what I wrote. Sure this won't work: `1 => (1(0), 1(1))`... There's a letter L...

Comment: @hateScala no problem, consider marking as correct / upvoting